# How Dim Loop and add 1 to Integer?

Tags: vb.net

i need help.
May be "loop" command is useful with this but i not know how to.
And sorry for bad English :P
Heres more detail;

I not want use anymore this code for my VB.Net application:

```
        Dim s As String = TypeHere.Text ' Heres target: TypeHere.Text
        Dim Words() As String = s.Split(New Char() {" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        If Words.Length > 0 Then
            c1 = Words(0)
            If Words.Length > 1 Then
                c2 = Words(1)
            End If
            If Words.Length > 2 Then
                c3 = Words(2)
            End If
            If Words.Length > 3 Then
                c4 = Words(3)
            End If
            If Words.Length > 4 Then
                c5 = Words(4)
            End If
            If Words.Length > 5 Then
                c6 = Words(5)
            End If
            If Words.Length > 6 Then
                c7 = Words(6)
            End If
            If Words.Length > 7 Then
                c8 = Words(7)
            End If
            If Words.Length > 8 Then
                c9 = Words(8)
            End If
            If Words.Length > 9 Then
                c10 = Words(9)
            End If
            If Words.Length > 10 Then
                c11 = Words(10)
            End If
            If Words.Length > 11 Then
                c12 = Words(11)
            End If
            If Words.Length > 12 Then
                c13 = Words(12)
            End If
            If Words.Length > 13 Then
                c14 = Words(13)
            End If
            If Words.Length > 14 Then
                c15 = Words(14)
            End If
            If Words.Length > 15 Then
                c16 = Words(15)
            End If
            If Words.Length > 16 Then
                c17 = Words(16)
            End If
            If Words.Length > 17 Then
                c18 = Words(17)
            End If
            If Words.Length > 18 Then
                c19 = Words(18)
            End If
            If Words.Length > 19 Then
                c20 = Words(19)
            End If
            CMDTime()
        End If
```

How i can do loop for do this?:

```
If Words.Length > ? Then
    Dim c?+1 = Words(?)
End If
```

If users entered words' length: 4
Auto generating:

```
    Dim c5 = Words(4)
    Dim c4 = Words(3)
    Dim c3 = Words(2)
    Dim c2 = Words(1)
    Dim c1 = Words(0)
```

Example for my program;
User > textbox.text > entered how much words > dim c1 > word1 , dim c2 ...

Comment: Hello! Is there a reason why you don't use the array `Words` instead of your `c` variables?

Comment: Well I can see why you don't want to do that code anymore, but I'm not sure why you want to create variables to hold each string from your array? What are you doing with the C1, C2, C3.... variables once you have populated them with word(x)? Why can't you just use your word() array wherever the C variables are now? Hoping I can help once I better understand what you're trying to do Mark

Comment: How are the `c?` variables defined right now? Where else are they used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use an array? I don't fully understand what you're trying to do as I can't see the full code.

```
    Dim s As String = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
    Dim Words() As String = s.Split(New Char() {" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim c(Words.Length - 1) As String
    For x = 0 To Words.Length - 1
        c(x) = Words(x)
    Next

    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("-", c))
    Console.WriteLine(c(0))
    Console.WriteLine(c(1))
```

Output:

```
The-quick-brown-fox-jumps-over-the-lazy-dog
The
quick
```

Comment: @HasanMerkit please choose this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

All you need are your first two lines of code:

```
Dim s As String = "Hello World"
Dim Words() As String = s.Split(New Char() {" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Then you can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Words.Length)
Console.WriteLine(Words(0))
Console.WriteLine(Words(1))
```

That produces:

```
2
Hello
World
```

It's just that where ever you use `c1` replace it with `Words(0)`, `c2` with `Words(1)`, etc. You would use `Words.Length` to know how many words you have.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is: No, you cannot do this:

```
    'Nooooo!
    If Words.Length > ? Then
        Dim c?+1 = Words(?)
    End If
```

But... you're a programmer, so everything is possible! Just not always as we picture it at first.

You cannot Dim variables in a loop with dynamic names, but there are alternatives. For one, you could have a list of variables to which you could add at every pass of your loop.

But it would not be enough, as you meant your variables names to be meaningful. So you would have to create a list of KeyValuePair. The Key would be the meaningful number and the value would be the string. Like this:

```
    Dim myList As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String))

    Dim index As Integer = 0
    For Each s As String In words
        index += 1
        myList.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)(index, s))
    Next
```

But, really, this method is kinda wonky and will be unnecessarily difficult to use.

On the other hand, you can declare the array `Words()` as a modular variable in your class and update it every time you need to use it. Your previous code snippet would be shorten to:

```
    Dim s As String = TypeHere.Text ' Heres target: TypeHere.Text
    Words = s.Split(New Char() {" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    If Words.Length > 0 Then
        CMDTime()
    End If
```

Now, you know that `Words(0)` is the same as c1. You can use Words(0) instead. Careful, though, because if you hard code an index like that, you may sometimes crash if you get out of bounds. You can avoid this by protecting your weak code inside `If Words.Length > x Then` blocks, just as you were doing before. Or, which I prefer, if you have to iterate through every entry in the array, do it in a `For Each` loop. If there are zero items in the array, this loop will not crash.

When you think about it, you were already doing this, or almost. You had the answer in you all along! Isn't this magic?

If this is not helpful, please try to precise what you're looking for. Somebody is sure to pick up the ball and help out!

Have fun!